# Showing just some part of a div

Tags: jquery, css

I want to have a div which is shown just top part of it (like 50px oh height) and other (bottom like 100px) part of the div should be shown by jquery.show() or something else. Is there anyone know how to do it ?

[image: Here is an image to help explain]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set the div height to 50px fixed and on click you can change the height to auto per javascript/jQuery, or revert it from auto to 50px.

CSS:

```
.mydiv{
  height:50px;
  min-height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".mydiv").click(function(){
    if($(".mydiv").css("height")!="50px"){
      $(".mydiv").slideDown();
    }
    else{
      $(".mydiv").slideUp();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd embed the content in a `<div id="foo" style="height: 50px; overflow:hidden">`. Then control the height of this element with JQuery:

```
$("#foo").css("height", whatever);
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id='example'>some content here</div>
```

CSS:

```
#example {height: 50px; overflow:hidden;}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#example').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({ height: 500px; }, 250);
}
```

Comment: it looks fine but are you sure that the syntax is correct, bcs it is giving warning in javascript part.

Comment: ok it is working without ";" like
    
$(this).animate({ height: 500px}, 250);

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the div to the height you want it to have from start (50px) through CSS. Set `overflow: hidden;` to hide the rest of the content.

After that you can do something like this to show the entire element:

```
$("#id-of-element-to-click-to-show-entire-div").click(function(){
   $(this).slideDown("fast");
});
```